# How to filter data inside of the navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Suppose that I have 2 tables "Form" and "Status". Form table contains some properties and the navigation property that refers to Status table.

```
// Form table model
public class Form
{
    ...Some properties,
    public ICollection<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
}
// Status table model
public class Status
{     
    ...Some properties,  
    public DateTime FormTimeStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime FormTimeFinish { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that, I want the entire data from Form table including Status, but I also want to filter the data from Status table if today is earlier than expired date or not.
Here is what I've tried, But it could not give any response.

```
var form = _context.Forms
                 .Include(s => s.Statuses.Where  
                   (i => DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,i.FormTimeFinish) < 0))
                 .Include(t => t.FormTopics)
                 .ThenInclude(q => q.Questions)
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in a single query. You'll need to explicitly load the `Statuses` relationship, after the fact:

```
var form = await _context.Forms
             .Include(t => t.FormTopics)
             .ThenInclude(q => q.Questions)
             .ToListAsync();

form.Statuses = await _context.Entry(form)
    .Collection(x => x.Statuses).Query()
    .Where(i => DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, i.FormTimeFinish) < 0))
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, be *very* careful with this, as you only have a subset of the statuses. So if you do anything like attempt to save the form, you'll end up deleting anything not in that list (it will look to EF as if you removed all the other statuses from the collection). It's best for this reason to disable tracking, in the initial query so that it will be more obvious that something's not right if you accidentally forget and attempt to save:

```
var form = await _context.Forms
    .Include(t => t.FormTopics)
    .ThenInclude(q => q.Questions)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: your code works fine, but I still don't get what you've said. So If I have a subset of statues which is not the entire data if I attempt to save that subset of data, it will overwrite the entire data. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Anything not included will effectively be deleted.

Comment: Just don't save the form instance. Or if you need to, then don't set the statuses there. Put them in a separate variable instead.